# Remove Java Loading image while loading Applet

Tags: java

I am using applet viewer for my Web Application.

Before loading the applet viewer, is it possible to remove the java loading image.

Please check the attachment.

Thanks -
Haan[image: I want to remove this image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the image parameter in [Special Attributes of Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#specialattributes).  To 'remove' the image you might simply replace it with a 1x1 transparent GIF, but a more meaningful loading image would be best.